# Request parameter is null , after submitting formdata AJAX with image

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**Important! This happen only in hosting server. Localhost no problem to upload**

---

I am trying to upload my image using AJAX to my laravel controller. By using dd($request), the request is empty

Javascript code:

```
function addLogo() {
        console.log('test');
        $('#logoinvois .msg').text('');
        $('#logoinvois .msg').hide();

        // var form = $('#form_invois_logo')[0];
        // var formData = new FormData(form);

        var formData = new FormData();
        var file_data = $('#logo_invois').prop('files')[0];
        formData.append('logo_invois', file_data);

        for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }

        // return;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/invois/add_logo',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);}});}
```

Laravel controller:

```
public function save_logo(Request $request)
{

    dd($request->all());
    $request->validate(
        [
            'logo_invois' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:500',
        ],
        [
            'logo_invois.required' => 'Pilih gambar',
            'logo_invois.mimes' => 'Jenis fail hanya jpeg,jpg,png',
            'logo_invois.max' => 'Saiz yang dibenarkan adalah kurang 500KB',

        ]
    );
```

Comment: Is the add_logo route pointing to the save_logo controller function?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, in localhost is doing alright uploading the image, but the issue when I deploy the web application on hosting server

Comment: Well instead of relying on random people who know limited information about your entire infrastructure, why don’t you do your own debugging and figure out the issue by looking through the logs and following the breadcrumbs. Laravel has logs and so should your server. Sometimes you just need to figure things out for yourself. At first glance, nothing looks wrong with everything you’ve shown in your post. You even say that it works locally, so figure out what is different between your local instance and your production instance.

Comment: return value from controller to console.log showing message indicate no image is submitted

Comment: Maybe someone had this issue and resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded back my route file to hosting folder. then, the problem solve.

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).